# Why are plots flipped when using freqz and comparing between Octave and SciPy?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, scipy, octave

When I plot response of these coefficients:

```
b=[1.01063287e+00, -1.46490341e+01,  9.94030209e+01, -4.19168764e+02, ...
  1.22949513e+03, -2.66000588e+03,  4.39112431e+03, -5.64225597e+03, ...
  5.70320516e+03, -4.55022454e+03,  2.85602975e+03, -1.39550096e+03, ...
  5.20372994e+02, -1.43160328e+02,  2.74037105e+01, -3.26098385e+00, ...
  1.81735269e-01];
a=[1.00000000e+00, -1.45159238e+01,  9.86464912e+01, -4.16614074e+02, ...
  1.22391361e+03, -2.65216678e+03,  4.38533779e+03, -5.64421414e+03, ...
  5.71487734e+03, -4.56742504e+03,  2.87187255e+03, -1.40575405e+03, ...
  5.25150201e+02, -1.44741759e+02,  2.77584882e+01, -3.30950845e+00, ...
  1.84797453e-01];
```

in Octave (which is OK):

```
pkg load signal
pkg load control

[h(:,1), w] = freqz(flip(b), flip(a),2048);
plot((w/pi),20*log10(abs(h(:,1))));
```

[image]

and in Python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import freqz

h = np.zeros(2048, float)
w = np.zeros(2048, float)

[h[:], w] = freqz(np.flip(b), np.flip(a), 2048)
  
plt.plot((w/np.pi),20*np.log10(h[:]));
plt.show()
```

[image]

, results are otherwise about equal but, as seen in plots, latter response is drawn something like twice turned compared to Octave's result.

What is going on and how to get equal plot with Octave from Python? I have tried by removing flip command from Python code but, response keeps being same.

Comment: What is the function `freqz` you use in Python? Please post a [mre], so we can see what you did.

Comment: Without having the complete data set, we can't try this ourselves.  And it is `scipy.signal.freqz`.  You don't need to write `h{;}` here; `h` will do.  And you don't have to initialize the arrays to zeros; `freqz` returns newly created arrays.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, scipy.signal.freqz. Hmm.. aren't there enough data and code for reproduce the issue?

Comment: @TimRoberts, I don't have data set other than a and b coefficients (though, these are ripped from 8th order system which I calculate with many functions not related to this issue as the final coefficients are equal between Octave and Python implementation.

Comment: No, there is not enough code. A [mre] means I can copy-paste the code and run it. If you force people to figure out which packages to import and how, then you’re asking them to do quite a bit of effort for you even before they can start figuring out why you have this problem. Some people here assumed you meant `scipy.signal.freqz` when you wrote `freqz`. It could just as well have been any number of other functions in other packages, there are way too many packages in the Python ecosystem. Be explicit, make it easy for people to help you!

Comment: OK, added missing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy.signal.freqz` returns (w,h), not (h,w) as you expect.

This should work:

```
w, h = freqz(np.flip(b), np.flip(a), 2048)

plt.plot(w/np.pi,20*np.log10(np.abs(h)))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of `scipy.signal.freqz`:

```
Returns
-------
w : ndarray
    The frequencies at which `h` was computed, in the same units as `fs`.
    By default, `w` is normalized to the range [0, pi) (radians/sample).
h : ndarray
    The frequency response, as complex numbers.


[...]


Notes
-----
Using Matplotlib's :func:`matplotlib.pyplot.plot` function as the callable
for `plot` produces unexpected results, as this plots the real part of the
complex transfer function, not the magnitude.
Try ``lambda w, h: plot(w, np.abs(h))``.
```

Comment: Thanks for the infos! This was helpful answer so +1. I'm new to Python and it's libraries so didn't bumb to  this documentation

Comment: In general, once you've imported a module, you can view its documentation or the documentation for any of its functions using the `help` command. E.g. in this case: `help( scipy.signal.freqz )`